# Asmack get NullPointerException at privacyManager.createPrivacyList

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

block user via Asmack , I'm getting NULL pointer Execption
I read the privacymanager doc and I don't know what is wrong why I get this NullPointerException  , 
note the connection is fine and I'm able to send and receive msgs 
any one can help

```
public void blockContact(String user) {
    try {
        PrivacyListManager privacyManager = PrivacyListManager
                .getInstanceFor(MyApplication.connection);

        // Set the name of the list
        String listName = "blocklist1";

        // Create the list of PrivacyItem that will allow or deny some
        // privacy aspect
        //

        List<PrivacyItem> privacyItems = new Vector<PrivacyItem>();

        PrivacyItem item = new PrivacyItem(PrivacyItem.Type.jid.name(),
                false, 1);
        item.setValue(user);
        item.setFilterMessage(true);
        privacyItems.add(item);
        Log.d(getLocalClassName() + "isFilterMessage : ",
                item.isFilterMessage() + "");


        privacyManager.createPrivacyList(listName, privacyItems);  //HERE
        privacyManager.addListener(this);   // AND HERE
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
10-05 11:51:16.649: W/System.err(25166): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 11:51:16.649: W/System.err(25166):    at com.app.chat.MyChat.blockContact(MyChat.java:807)
```

Comment: Hi please help me, I am also facing same problem